# LVM + pvs + how to get the pvs results

Tags: linux, awk, sed, rhel, lvm

we want to wrote command that take the `Pfree` size but with integer number not float number

```
 pvs
  PV         VG   Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sda2  vg   lvm2 a--  277.97g 111.97g
```

for example on below `pvs` we can do

```
pvs --units g | awk '{print $NF}' | sed s'/\./ /g' | awk '{print $1}' | tail -1
```

its gives

```
111
```

but on different case that we get two or more `PV` lines then need to calculate the total `Pfree`

example 1

```
pvs
  PV         VG   Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sda2  vg   lvm2 a--  149.51g 53.51g
  /dev/sda3  vg   lvm2 a--   50.00g   2.1g
```

example 2

```
   pvs
  PV         VG   Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sda2  vg   lvm2 a--  149.51g 520.00m
  /dev/sda3  vg   lvm2 a--   50.00g  3.51g
```

so we want to search lvm command that can gives that calculated results with Giga

regarding to example 1 , we should get `55.6`

or

regarding to example 2 , we should get `4.2`

any suggestion of lvm that already do this magic?

if not I will appreciate to get *awk/sed/perl* syntax that can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get only PV free space with `pvs`

```
# pvs -o pv_free --unit=g --no-suffix --no-heading 
   1.00
   0.31
```

and sum with `bc`

```
# pvs -o pv_free --unit=g --no-suffix --no-heading | paste -s -d+ - | bc
1.31
```

Answer (score 0):

Or a slightly inelegant and rather unnecessary use of awk (as compared to Vojtech's solution) that could be adapted to fit your purpose (since you've mentioned your desire for awk):

```
[root@localhost Documente]# lvs --no-heading --unit=g
  root cl -wi-ao---- 17,00g
  swap cl -wi-ao----  2,00g
[root@localhost Documente]# lvs --no-heading --unit=g | awk '{sum+=$4} END {print sum}'
19
```

But I'd personally stick with the simplicity in the answer above mine.